# Mapping Object to Multiple Attributes (Java)

Tags: java, lambda, maps, java-stream, mapping

learning about lambdas and streams in my java class and trying to get this one specific part figured out.

**Here is our assignment:** 
Use the class, Invoice, provided to create an array of Invoice objects. Class Invoice
includes four instance variables; partNumber (type String), partDescription (type String),
quantity of the item being purchased (type int0, and pricePerItem (type double). Perform
the following queries on the array of Invoice objects and display the results:

a. Use streams to sort the Invoice objects by partDescription, then display the
results.

b. Use streams to sort the Invoice objects by pricePerItem, then display the results.

c. Use streams to map each Invoice to its partDescription and quantity, sort the
results by quantity, then display the results

d. Use streams to map each Invoice to its partDescription and the value of the
Invoice (i.e., quantity * pricePerItem). Order the results by Invoice value.

e. Modify Part (d) to select the Invoice values in the range $200.00 to $500.00.

f. Find any one Invoice in which the partDescription contains the word “saw”.

**Where I'm at:** 
So I've got a) and b) down but I'm a little confused with part c). I haven't found anything online or in my book that suggests you can map an object to more than one of its own attributes. I've seen one example of this project where someone created a separate function where they created a String of the two elements combined, but I don't think my professor will give points for that because he said no modifications of his Invoice class. I'm wondering if he wants us to use a lambda to modify the toString method of Invoice, but that doesn't quite seem right because then we technically wouldn't be mapping the object of both attributes, just mapping to one and changing its output. Find his code (can't modify) below, and my code that I have so far.

**Professor's Code (can't be modified):**

```
public class Invoice {
   private final int partNumber; 
   private final String partDescription;
   private int quantity;
   private double price;

   // constructor
   public Invoice(int partNumber, String partDescription, int quantity, double price)
   {
      if (quantity < 0) { // validate quantity
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity must be>= 0");
      }

      if (price < 0.0) { // validate price
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Price per item must be>= 0");
      }

      this.partNumber = partNumber;
      this.partDescription = partDescription;
      this.quantity = quantity;
      this.price = price;
   }

   // get part number
   public int getPartNumber() {
      return partNumber; // should validate
   } 

   // get description
   public String getPartDescription() {
      return partDescription;
   } 

   // set quantity
   public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
      if (quantity <0) { // validate quantity
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Quantity must be>= 0");
      }

      this.quantity = quantity;
   } 

   // get quantity
   public int getQuantity() {
      return quantity;
   }

   // set price per item
   public void setPrice(double price) {
      if (price <0.0) { // validate price
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Price per item must be>= 0");
      }

      this.price = price;
   } 

   // get price per item
   public double getPrice() {
      return price;
   } 

   // return String representation of Invoice object
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return String.format(
         "Part #: %-2d  Description: %-15s  Quantity: %-4d  Price: $%,6.2f", 
         getPartNumber(), getPartDescription(), 
         getQuantity(), getPrice());
   } 
}
```

**Here's my code so far: **

```
// import statements
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class InvoiceDriver {

    //***************************************************************
    //  Method:       developerInfo
    //  Description:  The developer information method of the program
    //  Parameters:   none
    //  Returns:      n/a
    //**************************************************************
    public static void developerInfo() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
        System.out.println ("Name:    Allison Crenshaw");
        System.out.println ("Course:  ITSE 2317 Intermediate Java Programming");
        System.out.println ("Program: Five");
        System.out.println("*************************************************");
    } // End of developerInfo

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variables
        Invoice[] invoices = {
        new Invoice(83, "Electric sander",
                7, 57.98),
        new Invoice(24,"Power saw",
                18, 99.99),
        new Invoice(7, "Sledge hammer",
                11, 21.50),
        new Invoice(77, "Hammer",
                76, 11.99),
        new Invoice(39, "Lawn mower",
                3, 79.50),
        new Invoice(68, "Screwdriver",
                106, 6.99),
        new Invoice(56, "Jig saw",
                21, 11.00),
        new Invoice(3, "Wrench",
                34, 7.50)};

        // display developer info
        developerInfo();

        // welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to this Invoice Program.");
        System.out.println("This program receives invoice information " +
                "and displays");
        System.out.println("the info based on various sorts using lambdas " +
                "and streams.");
        System.out.println();

        // get list view of Invoices and use to stream and print
        List<Invoice> list = Arrays.asList(invoices);

        // use a st

        // a) use streams to sort the invoices by descriptions, then display
        System.out.println("Invoices sorted by description: ");
        Arrays.stream(invoices)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPartDescription))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        // b) use streams to sort the invoices by price, then display
        System.out.println("Invoices sorted by price: ");
        Arrays.stream(invoices)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPrice))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println();

        // c) use streams to map each invoice to its description and quantity,
        //    sort the results by quantity, then display the results
        System.out.println("Invoices mapped to description and quantity " +
                "and sorted by quantity: ");
        list.stream()
                .map(Invoice::getPartDescription)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        // d) use streams to map each invoice to its description and the
        //    value of the invoice (quantity * price) then order by value

        // e) modify part d) to select the invoice values in range $200-$500

        // f) find any one invoice in which description contains the word "saw"


    } // main

} // end InvoiceDriver
```

**Here's what the output is supposed to look like for part c): **

Invoices mapped to description and quantity:

Description: Lawn mower Quantity: 3

Description: Electric sander Quantity: 7

Description: Sledge hammer Quantity: 11

Description: Power saw Quantity: 18

Description: Jig saw Quantity: 21

Description: Wrench Quantity: 34

Description: Hammer Quantity: 76

Description: Screwdriver Quantity: 106

Comment: btw, which book are you using?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 The book we are using for this class is Java: How to Program, Early Objects – 11th Edition, Paul Deitel, Harvey Deitel – Pearson, 2017, (ISBN – 9780134751856), however, it doesn't have the greatest of examples for this particular programming assignment.

Comment: @beebus - I read that book too recently and I agree. I think most text books don't have enough exercises to test yourself thoroughly and remember the concepts well. I doubt if people will remember anything after solving only 10-15 exercises. I'd suggest to pick problems from multiple textbooks and do them all, besides questions on forums. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the element to anything you want, including, for example, a `String`:

```java
list.
    stream().
    sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getQuantity)).
    map(invoice -> 
        String.format(
            "Description: %-15s  Quantity: %-4d", 
            invoice.getPartDescription(), 
            invoice.getQuantity()
        )
    ).
    forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Looks like you already understand streams and lambdas well. So, I haven't added too much explanation in the code comments. Let me know if you need any explanations.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class InvoiceProcessor {

    //MAIN METHOD - START HERE !!!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Invoice> invoices = getInvoices();
        System.out.println("\nQuestion A:");
        partA(invoices);
        System.out.println("\nQuestion B:");
        partB(invoices);
        System.out.println("\nQuestion C:");
        partC(invoices);
        System.out.println("\nQuestion D:");
        partD(invoices);
        System.out.println("\nQuestion E:");
        partE(invoices);
        System.out.println("\nQuestion F:");
        partF(invoices);
    }

    //Generate some sample invoices to use in our code - using lambdas and streams!
    public static List<Invoice> getInvoices(){
        List<String> partNames = Arrays.asList("Lawn mower", "Electric sander", "Sledge hammer",
                "Power saw", "Jig saw", "Wrench", "Hammer", "Screwdriver");

        List<Invoice> invoices = IntStream
                .range(0, partNames.size())
                //Use each number to generate Invoices,i.e. 1 number is MAP-ped to 1 invoice.
                .mapToObj(n -> new Invoice(n, partNames.get(n), (n%3)+1, (n+1) * 50.0))
                //Collect all the invoices in a list.
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return invoices;
    }

    //a. Use streams to sort the Invoice objects by partDescription, then display the results.
    public static void partA(List<Invoice> invoices){
        invoices.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPartDescription))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    //b. Use streams to sort the Invoice objects by pricePerItem, then display the results.
    public static void partB(List<Invoice> invoices){
        invoices.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getPrice))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    //c. Use streams to map each Invoice to its partDescription and quantity, sort the results by quantity,
    // then display the results.
    public static void partC(List<Invoice> invoices){
        //Do we really need to do any mapping here?
        invoices.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Invoice::getQuantity))
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Description: " + i.getPartDescription() + " Quantity: " + i.getQuantity())
                );
    }

    //d. Use streams to map each Invoice to its partDescription and the value of the
    // Invoice (i.e., quantity * pricePerItem). Order the results by Invoice value.
    public static void partD(List<Invoice> invoices){
        //Do we really need to do any mapping here?
        invoices.stream()
                .sorted( Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice() ) )
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Description: " + i.getPartDescription() + " Invoice value: " + i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice())
                );
    }

    //e. Modify Part (d) to select the Invoice values in the range $200.00 to $500.00.
    public static void partE(List<Invoice> invoices){
        invoices.stream()
                .filter(i -> 200.0 <= i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice() && i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice() <= 500.0)
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println("Description: " + i.getPartDescription() + " Invoice value: " + i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice()));
    }

    //f. Find any one Invoice in which the partDescription contains the word "saw".
    public static void partF(List<Invoice> invoices){
        Invoice saw = invoices.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.getPartDescription().contains("saw"))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        System.out.println(saw);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have mapped the `Stream`, you would only be able to access the `partDescription` and not the `quantity` at the same time.

```
.map(Invoice::getPartDescription) // changed to Stream<String> from Stream<Invoice>
```

> Use streams to map each Invoice to its partDescription and quantity,
>   sort the results by quantity, then display the results

Thinking around to keep a tuple of both these attributes at the same time, a `Map` could be useful to collect the information for further processing(*sorting*). This would look like:

```
list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Invoice::getPartDescription,
                Invoice::getQuantity)) // map description to its quantity
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // sort by quantity (values of map)
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println("Description: " + e.getKey() + " Quantity: " + e.getValue()));
```

- You can follow up with a similar approach for section 'd' with a change in attributes.
- Further for section 'e' you would need to use `.filter` to selectively process the elements.
- Once you know how to `filter`, you need to `findAny` for section 'f' while you filter based on the given condition around the description.

Comment: Is there a way to do part d this without mapping to a list? So using streams to map each Invoice  to  its partDescriptionand  the  value  of  the Invoice (i.e., quantity* pricePerItem)??? It seems like you would use reduce but I haven't been able to get the correct syntax to calculate the value. I've tried (Invoice::getQuantity * Invoice::getPrice) without success. Any insight on how that would look?